# How to keep <br> in plaintext of php simplehtmlDOM

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

In [php simplehtmlDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) when I select a DIV and I want to read it's content. When I use `plaintext` it give me only texts without any html tags and when I use `innertext` it give me hypertext(text and html tag).

But I want to have a semi-hypertext text with `<br>` tag only or `\n`. what do I must do? please help me

Answer (score 1):

You should use [htmlspecialchars](http://id.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). It replaces characters as below:

```
<?php echo 'sample1&lt;br&gt;sample2'; ?>
```

- '&' (ampersand) becomes &
- '"' (double quote) becomes `&quot;` when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
- "'" (single quote) becomes `&#039;` only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
- '<' (less than) becomes `&lt;`
- '>' (greater than) becomes `&gt;`

Comment: I want keep <br> only and don't other and it cause keep all html